# Как добавить русский язык в Tesseract (python, Mac)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mac, tesseract, homebrew

`brew install tesseract --with-all-languages` и `brew install tesseract-lang` больше не работают. 
Как теперь можно добавить языки для tesseract (python, mac)?

mac - High Sierra 10.13.6 (17G9016), Python 3.5.2, brew 2.2.5

Comment: Версия?(mac, brew, python)

Comment: mac - High Sierra 10.13.6 (17G9016), Python 3.5.2, brew 2.2.5